# VS Code always gives error when trying to run code after switching to virtual env in python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

the error:

```
PS C:\Users\Prashant(Gaz)\fieldrocket-pygame\fieldrocket> & c:/Users/Prashant(Gaz)/fieldrocket-pygame/fieldrocket/pyfr/Scripts/Activate.ps1
Gaz : The term 'Gaz' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if 
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:21
+ & c:/Users/Prashant(Gaz)/fieldrocket-pygame/fieldrocket/pyfr/Scripts/ ...
+                     ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Gaz:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
PS C:\Users\Prashant(Gaz)\fieldrocket-pygame\fieldrocket>
```

so i made a virtual env through cmd, and then opened vs code, tried to switch the interpreter to the venv one, but it just gives me this error for no reason when i click on new terminal or runcode from right click menu.... this obviously works if i use the command as a string so why is vs code doing this please help...

If i manually activate venv it works just fine, but i cant quick run code because of this, idk why this happens sometimes....a few works ago i was working with django and never had this issue at all whilst using venv all the time

edit : the command is not something i typed it, i just opened a new terminal, even after activating venv manually if i re-open a new terminal, it gives the same error

Comment: I think that you need to have the same terminal open as long as you want the virtual environment running. Closing the terminal a venv is running in stops it. Also, as far as I know, there is no way of running commands in a venv from *outside* the terminal it is being run in.

Comment: i dont think u understand, there is something wrong with this...even after activating the venv manually and not killing the terminal, i face this error if i try to pip install something, i cant do anything in this venv, except running the file, except after execution it displays the same said error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move your virtual environment to some other place, which path without contains the `(` or `)`.

**Update:**

If you want to avoid automatically activate the virtual environment when you create a new terminal. you can add this in your settings.json file:

```
"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false,
```

Comment: i have a project with django and ity just works fine, whenever i open a new terminal it successfully activates a venv....it runs the same command but everything after the & is in a string.....im really confused and shocked as for why this happening

Comment: @Gaz P It can be work if it was contained in a string.

Comment: yes i tried it manually and it did, the command also runs as a string in my other django proj, but here as soon as i open a new terminal or  try to pip install anything, this command runs automatically without a string and gives an error....i cant do anything

Comment: @Gaz P Could you have a look at the update of the answer?

Comment: @Gaz P I still suggest you create a new virtual environment.

Comment: i did tried creating an entirely new directory made a file to print hello, created a venv, and then still got the same error, its unbelievable

although i tried this, "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false in json, and this has stopped vs code to automatically put that line in the terminal, so ig that's atleast fine for now...but still such a weird issue i dont even know what to do lol

Comment: @Gaz P Could you update the question to attach the error message?

Comment: the error i have inlcuded in the question is the same error i get everywhere..so im not sure what you mean? Like this the error im getting everywhere

Comment: @Gaz P You have created a new virtual environment, when you activate the environment,  you should not run across the same error. Have you selected the new virtual environment? It should not contains `(Gaz)` in the path.

Comment: so wait do u want me to create a folder outside my user folder? that i havent done yet...but why should i do that....

Comment: @Gaz P Your name: Prashant(Gaz) contains `(` and `)`, you should avoid it as my answer said.